# Xcode not showing release code signing option

Tags: xcode

I'm having a very uncommon issue with Xcode in a particular project.

Under Project > Targets > Code Signing > Code Signing Identity,

There is only the debug option.

Is there a way to bring this release option back so I can select my proper provision profile?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a release configuration under the project -> Info tab -> Configurations

[image]